# Can Mathematica solve this type of recurrence?

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, recursion

I have the following recursively defined equation:

```
 a[n_] := a[n] =  1 - Sum[Binomial[n, k] 2^(n - k - 1) a[k], {k, 0, n - 2}] -  2 n*a[n - 1]
 a[0] := a[0] = 1
 a[1] := a[1] = -1
 a[2] := a[2] = 3
```

I want to solve this particular recurrence equation using `RSolve`, but I'm not sure that *Mathematica* can handle recurrences of this type, based upon the particular outputs I'm getting.  Is there a way solve this type of recurrence using *Mathematica*?

I am looking for a closed form solution rather than computing `a` numerically.

Comment: I don't think `RSolve` can handle a recursion where $a_n$ is given as a function of *all* $a_k$ for $0\le k < n$ ... but I never dare say a categorical no :-)

Comment: You might make progress against this by using [**Guess** by Manuel Kauers.](http://www.kauers.de/software.html)

Answer (score 3):

One can certainly compute `a[n]` for arbitrary positive integer $n$.

```
a[n_] := 1 - Sum[Binomial[n, k] 2^(n - k - 1) a[k], {k, 0, n - 2}] - 2 n a[n - 1];
a[0] := 1;
a[1] := -1;
a[2] := 3;

a[15]
```

(*
$-694475294514315$
*)

```
 ListLogPlot[Table[a[i], {i, 1, 20}]]
```

[image]

Just note that many values of `a[i]` are negative and won't show up on the `ListLogPlot`.

However, attempts with `FindSequenceFunction[]` and `FindGeneratingFunction[]`, even with appropriate `FunctionSpace` restrictions failed:

```
FindSequenceFunction[Table[{n, a[n]}, {n, 0, 20}],
FunctionSpace -> {"ConstantRecursive", "Hypergeometric"}]
```

I think the difficulty lies in the parametric nature of the sum's limits.

Comment: `ListLogPlot[{Table[a[k], {k, 0, 15}], -Table[a[k], {k, 0, 15}]}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, Red}]`

Comment: @belisarius  That computes twice as many points as necessary (quite a penalty for large lists), but shows the results.  Simple interleaving (`Riffle`) of the even and odd values can fix that.

Comment: Use of memorization ( a[n_]  :=  a[n]  =  ... ) as shown in the original post would improve the efficiency. Although memorization and use of SetDelayed is not needed for the starting values of a[0], a[1], and a[2].

Comment: I appreciate the help.  I'm looking for a closed form for the a[n].  Looking at a log table helps to see what appears to be some linearity here so I'm confident we can find something.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven It's best to make this very clear in the question, especially after people have misunderstood it once (a bit of redundancy helps).  I made the edit for you.